# How can I generate public key for plaid link in JavaScript or C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, plaid

I'm creating a plaid link of v1 of plaid APIs,
now they have upgraded their APIs as v2,
Now if we want to create link then we must need to generate a public key with every new request and pass it into the create link API.

I want this in **c# or JavaScript**, but I didn't find any way as I have also does google it.
On the plaid documentation, they do not provide any way to generate a public key in **c# or JavaScript**

please anyone can help me to out to here.

Comment: Can you link to the part of their documentation that states you need to generate a public key? All I can see is _"To gain access to the Plaid API, please create an account on our Dashboard. Once you’ve completed the signup process and acknowledged our terms, we’ll provide a live client_id, secret, **and public_key** via the Dashboard."_

Comment: Or are you referring to [public tokens](https://plaid.com/docs/#creating-public-tokens)?

Comment: Yes, here is link please check https://plaid.com/docs/#creating-public-tokens

Comment: Here what they state that we need to generate public token with every request,  https://plaid.com/docs/link/transition-guide/#notable-changes

Comment: _"On the plaid documentation, they do not provide any way to generate a public [token]"_ .. but as the link we both posted says, to create a public token you have to make a POST request to `/item/public_token/create`

Comment: Yes, but this is in nodejs, i want in c# or JavaScript

Comment: .. then your question is actually _"How do I make a POST request in C# or JavaScript"_ - but if you've used their API you must surely already be doing that..? Anyway, you would use `HttpClient` in C# or `fetch` in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

For Plaid API V2 using javascript,

```
    Plaid.create({
        apiVersion: 'v2',
        env: '<your_environment>',
        clientName: '<your_client_id>',        
        key: '<your_public_key>',
        product: ['auth'],
        selectAccount: true,
        onSuccess: function (public_token, metadata) {
              // On success, you will get public token in response public_token & metadata.public_token
        },
        onExit: function (err, metadata) {}
    });
```